# Spring returning incorrect handler method

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Jboss 6.1,Spring 3.2, hibernate validation and with CORS support enabled recently. The request is working fine with GET method.I wanted the controller to return 405, if request method POST is used. But I am getting http status code 400 instead. I enabled the trace in jboss log and found that spring is returning a wrong handler. The applicaiton has only one controller that accepts a POST request method, rest of controllers are defined to accept only GET method. Whenever a request is made for these controllers(defined with GET) with POST request method, Spring is trying to find a handler, but it is somehow matching handler with POST method. Appreciate your help!

Web.xml with CORS options support

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring context xml file:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="localValidatorFactoryBean">
<mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="customObjectMapper" />
    </bean>
</mvc:message-converters>
```

This is my curl script:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" -d    '{"param1":"value1","param2":"value2"}' http://localhost:8080/api/myrequest
```

curl Response:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Spatial-Web-Service-Version: 2.0.0
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1079
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 23:14:11 GMT
Connection: close

This is my controller method, which uses hibernate bean validaton 1.1:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "myrequest", method = GET, produces = TEXT_XML_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public String getDetails(
@Valid DetailRequest detailRequest, BindingResult results, HttpServletResponse resp) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your RequestMapping method = POST,then try again